# Xamarin Android app working on Emulator failing on HockeyApp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, hockeyapp

Hi I am working on Xamarin Android app. It works fine on emulator but when I try to install it through Hockeyapp its crashes as soon as i open it. Can anyone help me ? I am not even sure what the issue could be?

Comment: have you tried looking at the Android device log?  Have you tried deploying directly to the device from the IDE?

Comment: You need to at least provide a crash report or log output that shows more details about the startup issue. In any way it can not be related to HockeyApp, as the OS downloads the file and installs it. HockeyApp doesn't alter your app in any way, it is identical to the file that you upload.